# About load byte instruction in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, twos-complement

I want to know about the processing of the MIPS **load byte (`lb`)** instruction. I found the question that asks me to fill the variable by given `byte@7=0x82, byte@8=0x6A`.

- `lb $s4,8($0)` (the answer is `$s4=6A`)
- `lhu $s5,7($0)` (the answer is `$s5=6A82`)
- `lb $s4,7($0)` (the answer is `$s4=FFFFFFF82`)

I think I'm understand in the 1st and 2nd question. But I don't really understand in the 3rd question that why the answer is `FFFFFFF82`. I will be very pleased if all of you can tell me about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a single byte into a 32 bit register with the `lb` instruction the MIPS architecture performs automatic [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). For the first example the value loaded (`0x64`) is positive, so the register contains `0x0000006a`. But for the last example the value is negative (`0x82` == -126) so the register will be sign-extended to `0xffffff82` (-126 expressed as a 32 bit signed value).

Note that the `lbu` instruction is the unsigned version of `lb` - it does not perform sign extension, so the high order bytes of the resulting load will always be zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I really understand. ^^